# Restrict library linking in C

Tags: c, gcc

If I want gcc compiler to throw an error if I include `stdlib.h` or a particular header, what flags should I use?. I don't want to use `-nostdlib` flag, because it doesn't link any standard libraries.

Comment: `stdlib.h` isn't a library, it's a header file. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I thought you wanted to throw an error if you forgot to include `stdlib.h`, why would you want to do that?

Comment: you may add some #error to the header itself, but why...

Comment: it's strange. you need to state your true problem. to answer your question, i think `#ifdef ... #error ... #endif` would help.

Comment: my guess is your compile machine is different from your running machine. that's what we call a cross compilation. but that's not achieved as you think. it's not good for you and us to hide the true problem. maybe the problem is larger than you think. state your problem clear, otherwise nobody is able to help you.

Comment: This question sounds like a case of the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: Since [stdlib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) defines the macro `EXIT_FAILURE`, following the advice of @HuStmpHrrr , you can try `#ifdef EXIT_FAILURE #error "stdlib is included" #endif`

Answer (score 3):

For each header file there is an include guard, so I guess you can try to check for it like this

```
#ifdef _STDLIB_H
#error "You should not include stdlib.h"
#endif
```

and then you can apply the same with other headers. Of course, this will only work with a particular `c` standard library in this case I took the include guard from `stdlib.h` in [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). And it will not work if you include `stdlib.h` after checking.

Also, a header file is not a library, it contains definitions and functions prototypes from libraries, if you don't want you program to link to the standard library you have no other option AFAIK than `gcc -nostdlib`.

Comment: strange for downvoting this answer, this is a good answer... as an addition, a function in standard library is not necessary to require head file included to link to shared object, as long as the prototype used everywhere is correct. so according to this perspective, there is no point to block including the head file only.

Comment: i agree - this is a good answer. The possible objection is that its not portable since the guard name will vary from platform to platorm

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr the downvote was because I gave a wrong answer before, because I understood the question wrong, check the edits. Also, it's not portable but if the OP is using `gcc` then probably it will be with `glibc`, but I think it would be good to mention that.

Comment: Also note that many standard headers will just "stub" the main include file to include more platform specific ones; some other files may end up including those platform-specific includes themselves, so you really don't gain a whole lot by simply disabling `stdlib.h` --